# Adding a signedInfo to an OpenSSL CMS signature

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to create a CMS signature using OpenSSL. While I'm able to create a regular signature, my application has some requirements I'm unable to meet.

My application requires me to add a signedAttr with the OID 1.2.840.113635.100.9.1 to the signature, but I'm unable to do that. I'm also unable to find any APIs which would allow me to accomplish the same.

I have uploaded two CMS messages which meet the specification at https://transfer.sh/96w2l/sigARM64 and https://transfer.sh/kbmBO/sigARM.

I'd be grateful if anyone here could point me in the right direction.

Comment: As is tradition, I'll be answering my own question once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add the attr to a SignerInfo and then use it to sign the CMS_ContentInfo.

```
#include <openssl/cms.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <string.h>

char *lol = "roflcopter";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    int flags = CMS_BINARY | CMS_PARTIAL | CMS_NOSMIMECAP | CMS_DETACHED;
    int ret = -1;

    BIO *bio_cert_and_key = BIO_new_file("/home/umang/.isign/pair.pem", "r");
    if (!bio_cert_and_key)
        goto err;

    X509 *scert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_cert_and_key, NULL, 0, NULL);
    BIO_reset(bio_cert_and_key);
    EVP_PKEY *skey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio_cert_and_key, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (!scert || !skey)
        goto err;

    BIO *in = BIO_new_file("/tmp/test2", "r");

    CMS_ContentInfo *cms = CMS_sign(NULL, NULL, NULL, in, flags);
    if (!cms)
        goto err;

    CMS_SignerInfo *si = CMS_add1_signer(cms, scert, skey, NULL, flags);
    ASN1_OBJECT *obj = OBJ_txt2obj("1.2.840.113635.100.9.1", 1);

    if (!si || !obj)
        goto err;

    if (!CMS_signed_add1_attr_by_OBJ(si, obj, 0x4, lol, strlen(lol)) || !CMS_SignerInfo_sign(si))
        goto err;

    int len = i2d_CMS_ContentInfo(cms, NULL);
    unsigned char *buf = malloc(len);
    unsigned char *buf_2 = buf;
    i2d_CMS_ContentInfo(cms, &buf);

    BIO *out = BIO_new_file("/tmp/test", "wb");
    if (!out)
        goto err;
    BIO_write(out, buf_2, len);

    ret = 0;

err:
    BIO_free(bio_cert_and_key);
    BIO_free(in);
    BIO_free(out);
    CMS_ContentInfo_free(cms);
    ASN1_OBJECT_free(obj);
    EVP_PKEY_free(skey);
    X509_free(scert);
    free(buf_2);

    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return ret;
}
```